# Can we create custom Rust operators?

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I know we can implement traits that override the standard arithmetic operators. Can we also create our own traits that overload custom operators? I have come to really enjoy Haskell's system for defining operators.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, per [the manual](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) the only operators that can be overloaded are:

> - `!` — Bitwise or logical complement
> - `!=` — Nonequality comparison
> - `%` — Arithmetic remainder
> - `%=` — Arithmetic remainder and assignment
> - `&` — Bitwise AND
> - `&=` — Bitwise AND and assignment
> - `*` — Arithmetic multiplication
> - `*=` — Arithmetic multiplication and assignment
> - `+` — Arithmetic addition
> - `+=` — Arithmetic addition and assignment
> - `-` — Arithmetic negation
> - `-` — Arithmetic subtraction
> - `-=` — Arithmetic subtraction and assignment
> - `/` — Arithmetic division
> - `/=` — Arithmetic division and assignment
> - `<<` — Left-shift
> - `<<=` — Left-shift and assignment
> - `<` — Less than comparison
> - `<=` — Less than or equal to comparison
> - `==` — Equality comparison
> - `>` — Greater than comparison
> - `>=` — Greater than or equal to comparison
> - `>>` — Right-shift
> - `>>=` — Right-shift and assignment
> - `^` — Bitwise exclusive OR
> - `^=` — Bitwise exclusive OR and assignment
> - `|` — Bitwise OR
> - `|=` — Bitwise OR and assignment

Comment: Do you know if there are any plans to add this functionality? Or, plans to never add this functionality? Thanks

Comment: I would assume (and I have a vague recollection) that Graydon (Rust's BFDL) dislikes it and would prefer to keep it out of the language. But from a cursory search, I can't find any references for this claim.